# How to convert date like "Apr 15 2014 16:21:16 UTC" to UTC time using python

Tags: python, datetime

I have dates in the following format that are used to name zip files:

```
Apr 15 2014 16:21:16 UTC
```

I would like to convert that to UTC numbers using Python. Does python recognize the 3-character month?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime(yourstring, '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S UTC')
```

`%b` is the abbreviated month name. By default, Python uses the `C` (English) locale, regardless of environment variables used.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> yourstring = 'Apr 15 2014 16:21:16 UTC'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(yourstring, '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S UTC')
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 15, 16, 21, 16)
```

The value is timezone neutral, which for UTC timestamps is fine, provided you don't mix local objects into the mix (e.g. stick to [`datetime.datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) and similar methods).

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("Apr 15 2014 16:21:16 UTC")
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 15, 16, 21, 16, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Timezone is handled, and it supports other common datetime formats as well.